# mysql_data_seek error in ff and chrome, but works in ie

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

So I'm posting `$_POST['location']` using AJAX in my `script.js` file and the form on the previous page.  My problem is that this works in IE, but gives me the following error in ff and chrome:

```
Warning: my_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]:
Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 2 (or the query data is unbuffered)
in ...reserveAPickupAppointmentDateResults.php on line 39
```

I know the data is in the database, but in the past, I've usually only gotten that error when the SQL returns no entries.  I assume it is a problem with the SQL?

`reserveAPickupAppointmentDateResults.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

//create database connection
$connection = mysql_connect("XXXX","XXXX","XXXX"); 

//in case database connection fails
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database connection failed: ".mysql_error());
}   
else
{
    //select database to use
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("XXXX",$connection);

    //in case database selection fails
    if (!$db_select)
    {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
    } 
    else
    {
        $appointmentLocation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);
        $_SESSION["location"] = $appointmentLocation;

        $sql =  "SELECT timeBlocks.location, timeBlocks.date
        FROM timeBlocks
        WHERE timeBlocks.location = '".$appointmentLocation."';";

        //set results to variables
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result)
        {
            die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
        }

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        ?>

        <form class="reserveAPickupAppointmentForm5" id="reserveAPickupAppointmentForm5">
        <table>

        <?php
        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>
            <tbody class="reserveAPickupAppointmentDateResults">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="reserveAPickupAppointmentDateText">
                            <img src="images/reserveAPickupAppointmentButton1.png" class="reserveAPickupAppointmentDate">
                            <?php echo $row["date"]; ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>We have the following dates available for your location.  If you would like a different date, please choose "request a custom date" to try to schedule a custom appointment.  Otherwise, please choose a different date.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        </table>
        </form>

        <?php
    }
}

// Close connection 
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Relevant scripting from `formScript.js`

```
$(".reserveAPickupAppointmentDateText").click (function() {
    appointmentLocation = $(this).text();
    $.post(
        'reserveAPickupAppointmentTimeResults.php',
        {
            'date': date,
            'location': appointmentLocation,
            'appointmentSize': appointmentSize
        },

        function (response)
        {
            $("#reserveAPickupAppointmentTimeResults").html(response);
        }
    );

    return false;
});
```

Comment: If it works in one browser but not in another, it is a client-side problem not a server-side one. Can you post the javascript?

Comment: Why do you use mysql_data_seek() anyway? What's the point of `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` just before that?

Comment: sure, give me just a minute to get it pasted, also, I removed the class and ids that are the same...that was from an old version, sorry about the messiness

Comment: Also, the HTML is invalid. The last `<tr><td>` is not closed

Comment: @mchl thanks for that, its fixed, but still erroring.

Comment: @mchl so I could call the $row["x"] variable, then i start the pointer at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for this to be browser specific, I suspect what is actually going on is that IE doesn't render the error message whereas chrome and FF do. If you look in the source code, you will likely see the error message there under IE - if the generated source is different depending on the browser, something very odd is going on.

A more important point is that your call to `mysql_data_seek()` is pointless and doesn't do anything useful.

You call:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

But you never do anything with `$row`, then you call:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

before entering the loop. If you remove both of these lines, it will have no effect on the end result but should get rid of the error.

**EDIT**

If you really are getting different content generated in different browsers, then the problem is most likely that `appointmentLocation` in not being populated correctly in the Javascript in FF and Chrome, and as a result the SQL query is returning no results. In this case, you should examine the Javascript where you are assigning a value to `appointmentLocation`.

Comment: but I use $row['date'] in my table

Comment: You use `$row` in the loop, but you don't use it between the two lines I mention above. RE the no error in IE issue, see edit above.

Comment: thank you for your edit response...I have just confirmed that $appointmentLocation is being passed correctly to both ff and chrome by echoing it successfully in the same file. I too believe the sql query is messed up but I can't figure out why

Comment: try echoing `$sql` to look at the query that is generated, and `mysql_num_rows($result);` - I suspect your query is getting no results

Comment: okay! now I think we are getting somewhere...it looks like I am not escaping correctly in the sql (maybe?)...but I'm still not quite sure exactly how to fix it the $sql reads "...WHERE timeBlocks.location = '\n Briscoe'...

Comment: Try changing `$appointmentLocation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']);` to `$appointmentLocation = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['location']));`

Comment: yes, that definately worked, thank you. Do you have any idea where that /n is coming from?  I don't see any extra lines or spaces

Comment: It is coming from somewhere in your Javascript. Please edit the question and show the code where you assigned a value to `appointmentLocation`

Comment: also, I really appreciate you helping me with some extra debugging ideas, I will certainly remember those next time.

Comment: okay, updated, it was just one line for appointmentLocation, the other variables come from larger blocks

Comment: What type of HTML element is being selected by `.reserveAPickupAppointmentDateText`? Is it an `<input>`, `<a>`, `<textarea>` etc?

Comment: ah, I tracked it down, thanks for getting me started, it is an image tag included in the wrong span...and that span eventually is picked up by the js to get appointmentLocation.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem :-) NB from the [jQuery docs on `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/): `Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);` if you remove `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` line just before it. And you can remove that line , since you're not using `$row` variable for anything anyway.

The `Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index` error message suggests that your query returned 0 rows. Try to find out why.

Comment: but I am using $row['date'], in my table

Comment: Yes, and but you're doing `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` which assigns data to it.

Comment: it did, indeed get rid of the error, but im still getting no results in chrome or ff...I still suspect a problem with the sql

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are not defining your `POST` variables anywhere in your `click` function.

You probably need something like (depending on your form / html):

```
$(".reserveAPickupAppointmentDateText").click (function() {

  var appointmentLocation = $("#appointmentlocation").val();
  // and all other variables

  $.post(
    // etc.
```

Comment: sorry, they are defined much earlier, but there is a lot of code associated with those parts, I'm just trying to slim it down for the post

Comment: @radleybobins I would add a `console.log(appointmentLocation)` before your call to `$.post` to check if it really is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I just echoed $appointmentLocation successfully in reserveAPickupAppointmentDateResults.php in chrome and ff

Comment: I just echoed $appointmentLocation successfully in reserveAPickupAppointmentDateResults.php in chrome and ff (sorry i pushed edit instead of add commend by accident)

Comment: @radleybobins If IE is giving different results than Firefox or Chrome, IE is not sending the same stuff as the other two, your php file does not care about which browser you are using, just the information posted to it.